# Performing re.search() until end of line, and then updating dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

My question is a little odd, maybe someone can provide some guidance. I have a line of text that I need to search through and pull out multiple recurring strings to populate a dataframe. Given the following line:

`txt = "Tier : 'ONE' (random junk) Name : 'red' (random junk) Wire : 'R'(random junk) Name : 'blue' (random junk) Wire: 'B' (random junk) Name : 'orange' (random junk) Name: 'yellow' (random junk) Wire : 'Y'"`

I want to regex through and pull out **ONLY** complete Name/Wire pairs (in this example not `Orange`).

expected output

```
Tier   Name    Wire
 One   red      R
 One   blue     B
 One   yellow   Y
```

Code

```
for line in txt:
    line = line.strip()
    a = re.search(r' Tier : \'((?:(?![(]).)*)\'', line)
    if a:
        b = re.search(r' Name : \'((?:(?![(]).)*)\'', line)
        if b:
            c = re.search(r' Wire : \'((?:(?![(]).)*)\'', line)
            df = df.append({'Tier' : a.group(1),'Name' : b.group(1), 'Wire' : c.group(1)}, ignore_index=True)
```

This code produces the following df:

```
Tier    Name    Wire
 One     red      R
```

This behavior is expected, as `re.search()` only runs until it finds the item in question the first time.

OK, `re.search()` wont work, so I will try `re.findall()` instead:

```
for line in txt:
    line = line.strip()
    a = re.search(r' Tier : \'((?:(?![(]).)*)\'', line)
    if a:
        b = re.findall(r' Name : \'((?:(?![(]).)*)\'', line)
        if b:
            c = re.findall(r' Wire : \'((?:(?![(]).)*)\'', line)
            df = df.append({'Tier' : a.group(1),'Name' : b, 'Wire' : c}, ignore_index=True)
```

This will spit out the following df:

```
 Tier      Name                                    Wire
 One      ['red','blue','orange','yellow']        ['R','B','Y']
```

The issue with this dataframe is that now we no longer know what `Name` is associated with what `Wire`. Is there any way to have re.search() continue even after the first hit if it hasn't reached the end of the txt line? Anyone have any creative ideas on how to regex the line of text for only elements that contain everything(i.e. 'Name' **AND** 'Wire)? note: Pandas 23.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
for line in txt:
    line = line.strip()
    a = re.search(r"Tier\s*:\s*'([^']*)'", line)
    if a:
        res = re.findall(r"Name\s*:\s*'([^']*)'(?:(?!Name\s*:).)*?Wire\s*:\s*'([^']*)'", line)
        for name, wire in res:
            df=df.append({'Tier' : a.group(1),'Name' : name, 'Wire' : wire}, ignore_index=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N14coJ/1).

Note that the `Tier` regex is changed to `Tier\s*:\s*'([^']*)'` to match

- `Tier` - the word `Tier`
- `\s*:\s*` - a `:` char enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `'` - a `'` char
- `([^']*)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than `'`
- `'` - a `'` char.

The *name/wire* regex is

- `Name` - a `Name` word
- `\s*:\s*` - a `:` char enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `'` - a `'` char
- `([^']*)` - Group 1 (name): any 0 or more chars other than `'`
- `'` - a `'` char
- `(?:(?!Name\s*:).)*?` - any char (`.`), zero or more repetitions but as few as possible (`*?`), that does not start a `Name`, zero or more whitespaces and then `:` sequence (see `(?!Name\s*:)`)
- `Wire` - a `Wire` word
- `\s*:\s*` - a `:` char enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `'` - a `'` char
- `([^']*)` - Group 2 (wire): any 0 or more chars other than `'`
- `'` - a `'` char

Comment: Wow very cool stuff, this will be very very helpful to me and I have learned a lot! Thank you!!!